# Click image to animate (move) to the right

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

Trying, but failing, to use the animate() method to move an image to the right by 250px when it has been clicked.

I can do this OK with a button, however struggling when using the image as a 'button'.

HTML

```
<div class="runner-animation"> 
    <h1> Click to see how fast the runner moves! </h1>
    <img src="Images/runner-clip-art.png" id="runner">
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#runner").click(function(){
    $("#runner").animate({right: '250px'});
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Does the image have the css position property set to fixed/relative/absolute?

Comment: Please, provide any jsfiddle

Comment: @Taplar no CSS yet, no.

Comment: Try that.  IIRC without a position, top/bottom/left/right are ignored

Comment: @Taplar is IIRC bootstrap? I want to use jQuery only.

Comment: @Taplar I want to use jQuery only is possible, no plugins.

Comment: @StefanoMaglione I'm not sure how to use this, apologies. I'm in the very early stages of learning. Apologies. Do you think it's possible without using any plugins?

Comment: Plugins are not your issue -- check your CSS. If the image is simply placed by default, changing the position can't happen. Simply by adding the css to position it, either relative or absolute, makes this work fine.

Comment: IIRC = If I Recal Correctly.  It's an acronym.  I'm not saying use a plugin... @KaliMa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as you have the image positioned, pure jQuery works fine.

That said, you were missing a closing bracket and parenthesis in your code...

EDIT: You wanted to know how to reset the animation after it has run. The code below has been changed somewhat: first, the animation includes a few additional parameters -- a time and a function that runs when the animation is complete. In this function, I have hidden the h1 tag, and displayed a reset button. The code for the reset button simply reverts the image to its original CSS position, hides the reset button and redisplays the H1 tag.

Hope this helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#runner").click(function() {
    $("#runner").animate({
      left: '250px'
    }, 200, function(){ 
      // When animation is complete, display the reset button.
      $('h1').hide();
      $('.reset').show()
    });
  });
  
  $(".reset").on("click", function(){
    $('h1').show();
    $(this).hide();
    $("#runner").css('left', '0px');
  });
});
```

```css
#runner {
  position: relative;
}

.reset {
 display:none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="runner-animation">
  <h1> Click to see how fast the runner moves! </h1>
  <p><button class="reset">Reset my runner!</button></p>
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRi-GA_UEaos9P4H5dWe31rt-00En4KB6sE3RydFX91WGXKMpz1" id="runner">
</div>
```

Comment: This was perfect thank you. Do you know how I would reset the animation to go back to the start by clicking?

Comment: @KaliMa I've edited the above code to do exactly that. Best of luck!